# Unknown Error with routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey I am new to Rails and I keep getting this error when ever I go to localhost:3000/

Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

This is what my routes.rb file looks like.

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/about"
  get "static_pages/contact"
  get "static_pages/help"
  get "static_pages/home"

end
```

and my views folder looks like this

```
views/static_pages/about.html.erb
views/static_pages/contact.html.erb
views/static_pages/help.html.erb
views/static_pages/home.html.erb
```

I ran the rake routes command and got the following:

```
Davids-MacBook-Air:sample_app DavidStevenson$ rake routes
   static_pages_home GET /static_pages/home(.:format)    static_pages#home
   static_pages_help GET /static_pages/help(.:format)    static_pages#help
  static_pages_about GET /static_pages/about(.:format)   static_pages#about
static_pages_contact GET /static_pages/contact(.:format) static_pages#contact
```

Any ideas whats going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You simply forgot to define your root route. Put this at the end of your `routes` file:

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

You will now see the static_pages_home page when you will visit `localhost:3000/`.

Check [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to get all informations you need about routes.

EDIT

Here is how your `routes` file should look like:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/about"
  get "static_pages/contact"
  get "static_pages/help"
  get "static_pages/home"

  root to: 'static_pages#home'
end
```

Comment: so what should the format of the routes.rb file look like? Like this?     get "static_pages/about" root to: 'static_pages#about'

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a root route set up, and `"/"` is trying to match against it. Put it at the end.

```
# config/routes.rb
root to: "static_page#home"
```

Answer (score 1):

add the root route

```
root :to => 'static_pages#home'
```

put it at the end of the routes block